# Loaded Image Doesn't Retain Separate Colors in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I have an image of a map loaded in MATLAB.

BEFORE the map is loaded into MATLAB the appearance is:

US Continent: Green

Ocean: Blue

Canada: Yellow

AFTER I load the map it is displaying:

Canada and the US as one color BUT I need to separate them by colors.

My code is:

```
im = double(imread('US.png'))
figure;
colormap summer;
...
```

Comment: Does removing `colormap summer` not fix this?

Comment: Nope.  On a gray scale it makes Canada and US white.

Comment: Did you check the actual values of `im` once loaded? Do these correspond to the three (pure) color values you see before loading (red, green, blue)? Do they give 3 distinct values after `rgb2gray`? If yes, then maybe your problem is with scaling the displayed image.

Answer (score 0):

As a rough guess, I'm assuming you are not properly scaling your intensity (color) values, i.e. not in [0, 1], so any value above 1 is mapped by the colormap (any color or grayscale)   to the same value.

As long as `length(unique(im))==3` (three distinct indices for the three gray-scale values that you see before loading), then both of the following should scale your visual output:

```
imshow(im, []); colormap summer;
imshow(im./max(im(:))); colormap summer;
```